# How to add a layer with city names into QGIS project?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, cartography

I am new to GIS technologies and I wonder how to add a layer with city names to the QGIS project. I have two layers: (1) Base cartography that is a map without any labels, (2) Delimited text layer that shows some points on the map.

I assume that I should add another layer, but I don't know where can I find appropriate data. Which format should I search for? SHP or any other?

To be more concrete, I need this information for Spain.

Comment: Are the names already present in the delimited text layer?

Comment: Does the delimited text layer contain coordinates of the points? Then you can add it with `Add delimited text`,  and label it with the names field.

Comment: If the two layers have a common field you can join them together to combine the spatial attributes from the first and the information from the second. Or alternatively you can download one of the many ready datasets that exist out there. FOr example http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/equipamiento.do?method=descargarEquipamiento&codEquip=8

Comment: OR http://www.mapcruzin.com/free-spain-arcgis-maps-shapefiles.htm (sorry for double commenting but I couldn't edit the comment above)

Answer (score 3):

You could try the '[Populated Places](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-populated-places/)' layer from Natural Earth:

[image]

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-populated-places/